# Cap deploy:setup stuck at sftp command (using Simone Carletti's recipe for database.yml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I m deploying my rails 3 app with capistrano and I can't figure out why at some point during cap deploy:setup task the command line is waiting on a sftp command.

I searched into the recipe where this command is sent in order to understand but couldn't find it.

As sidenote, I'm using Simon [Carlett's recipe](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/) to generate the database.yml file instead of storing & fetching it on github).

Here it is my output :

```
/var/www/odpf/config$ cap deploy:setup
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-01-07 09:03:03 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/odpf /var/www/odpf/releases /var/www/odpf/shared /var/www/odpf/shared/system /var/www/odpf/shared/log /var/www/odpf/shared/pids"
    servers: ["*****"]
Enter passphrase for /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa: 
    [*****] executing command
 ** [out :: *****]
    command finished in 355ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:setup'
  * 2014-01-07 09:03:12 executing `deploy:db:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/odpf/shared/db"
    servers: ["*****"]
    [*****] executing command
 ** [out :: *****]
    command finished in 350ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/odpf/shared/config"
    servers: ["*****"]
    [*****] executing command
 ** [out :: *****]
    command finished in 350ms
    servers: ["*****"]
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x000000010579f8> -> /var/www/odpf/shared/config/database.yml
```

After this last instruction, the command line seems to wait infinitely...
I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and some ruby error are outputed :

```
^C/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:25:in `select': Interrupt
etc...
```

I looked into this file around line 25 and found this :

```
  21> readers = sessions.map { |session| session.listeners.keys }.flatten.reject { |io| io.closed? }
  22> writers = readers.select { |io| io.respond_to?(:pending_write?) && io.pending_write? }
  23>
  24> if readers.any? || writers.any?
  25>   readers, writers, = IO.select(readers, writers, nil, wait)
  26> else
  27>   return false
  28> end
```

Here it is Simone Carletti's recipe :

```
#
# = Capistrano database.yml task
#
# Provides a couple of tasks for creating the database.yml
# configuration file dynamically when deploy:setup is run.
#
# Category::    Capistrano
# Package::     Database
# Author::      Simone Carletti
# Copyright::   2007-2009 The Authors
# License::     MIT License
# Link::        http://www.simonecarletti.com/
# Source::      http://gist.github.com/2769
#
#

unless Capistrano::Configuration.respond_to?(:instance)
  abort "This extension requires Capistrano 2"
end

Capistrano::Configuration.instance.load do

  namespace :db do

    desc <<-DESC
      Creates the database.yml configuration file in shared path.

      By default, this task uses a template unless a template
      called database.yml.erb is found either is :template_dir
      or /config/deploy folders. The default template matches
      the template for config/database.yml file shipped with Rails.

      When this recipe is loaded, db:setup is automatically configured
      to be invoked after deploy:setup. You can skip this task setting
      the variable :skip_db_setup to true. This is especially useful
      if you are using this recipe in combination with
      capistrano-ext/multistaging to avoid multiple db:setup calls
      when running deploy:setup for all stages one by one.
    DESC
    task :setup, :except => { :no_release => true } do

      default_template = <<-EOF
      base: &base
        adapter: sqlite3
        timeout: 5000
      development:
        database: #{shared_path}/db/development.sqlite3
        <<: *base
      test:
        database: #{shared_path}/db/test.sqlite3
        <<: *base
      production:
        database: #{shared_path}/db/production.sqlite3
        <<: *base
      EOF

      location = fetch(:template_dir, "config/deploy") + '/database.yml.erb'
      template = File.file?(location) ? File.read(location) : default_template

      config = ERB.new(template)

      run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/db"
      run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      put config.result(binding), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    end

    desc <<-DESC
      [internal] Updates the symlink for database.yml file to the just deployed release.
    DESC
    task :symlink, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    end

  end

  after "deploy:setup",           "db:setup"   unless fetch(:skip_db_setup, false)
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "db:symlink"

end
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I decided to upgrade to Capistrano 3.x thinking that maybe it would solve my problem as it use ssh-kit instead of sftp.

It did not solved this issue.

I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076725/net-scp-waiting-until-time-out-in-capistranos-gitwrapper-task) linked to Capistrano 3.x and found the solution.

**This might be as well the solution for Capistrano 2.x though I didn't tested it**. So I post here this possible solution in case somebody is interested to test it.

In fact in Capistrano 3.x the, issue was linked to net-scp that is bugged since year 2000. So maybe sftp work the same way as net-scp.

The problem was coming from my .bashrc file (and the echo commands I put into) that is being executed during the ssh connexion (non-login, non-interactive).
More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076725/net-scp-waiting-until-time-out-in-capistranos-gitwrapper-task)

If anyone test it successfully, please tell us about it.

my few cents on this.