# net-scp waiting until time-out in capistrano's git:wrapper task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 2.1 with capistrano 3.0.1 deployement, and I'm facing issue with the git:check task :

```
douglas@bilbo:/var/www/odpf$ cap production git:check --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
 INFO [01658950] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/odpf/ on phisa-odpf-vd.vserver.nimag.net
DEBUG [01658950] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/odpf/
DEBUG [01658950]    === Lancement de /home/rvm_admin/.bashrc ===
 INFO [01658950] Finished in 0.629 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
cap aborted!
=== Lancement de /home/rvm_admin/.bashrc ===
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:392:in `await_response_state'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `call'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `process'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `block in preprocess'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `each'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:279:in `upload!'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:81:in `upload!'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
```

The last line of code that the ruby debugger gave is about `await_response_state`, so I guess that ssh-kit doesn't get an answer and timed out. I can't figure why though ???

I dug into **`/home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails3/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake`** and found this at the stucked line 13 :

```
  upload! StringIO.new("#!/bin/sh -e\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \"$@\"\n"), "#{fetch(:tmp_dir)}/#{fetch(:application)}/git-ssh.sh"
```

The parameters for this command are like chinese for me and I can't dig deeper.

If anybody could help me on this issue (either with capistrano, or with bash & ruby for the parameters) I would be gratefull.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

Capistrano use ssh to connect to my server.

Though most people would tell you that when you connect as non-login and non-interactive shell (with a script in ssh) [no file will be executed](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) :

**This is not always true !**

I checked the man page of Bash and found this interesting part :

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard
>   input connected to a a network connection, as if by the remote shell
>   daemon, usually rshd, **or the secure shell daemon sshd. If bash
>   determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes
>   commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable.** It
>   will not do this if invoked as sh. The --norc option may be used to
>   inhibit this behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force
>   another file to be read, but rshd does not generally invoke the shell
>   with those options or allow them to be specified.

So I checked my `~/.bashrc` file and realize I put some echo commands to check different environnment variable. Nothing harmfull.... at first glance.

I managed to test scp command solo on the bash and it was failing. That was weird because it was working at some point in the past.
I searched in google and found a similar issue : **SCP is bugged. When your .bashrc output some echo command, it get screwed up.**

The cause of all my problems was coming from a **bug in scp that is not going to be fixed by the developers**. This is unfortunate in my case.

Here it is an inquiry made by someone else on a similar problem : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error
And here it is the **SCP bug dating from year 2000 !!!** https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527

To solve it, I commented my "echo commands" at the beginning of my `~/.bashrc` file :

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
#
# These are my echo command checks
#echo '=== Execution of /home/rvm_admin/.bashrc ==='
#[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
#shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'#echo "Agent forwarding ? => SSH_AUTH_SOCK = $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
#echo '=== End of echo commands by Douglas ==='
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a check for interactive shell in .bashrc also solves the problem.

Let's say your echo commands are in a function.

```
function echoCheck()
{
    echo '=== Execution of /home/rvm_admin/.bashrc ==='
    [[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
    shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'#echo "Agent forwarding ? => SSH_AUTH_SOCK = $SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
    echo '=== End of echo commands by Douglas ==='
}
```

Add this to your .bashrc and problem will be solved.

```
[ ! -z "$PS1" ] && echoCheck
```